# How to set different z-index for firefox and ie?

Tags: css

index css property value 101 but I need 99 in firefox.

I tried like this

```
<!--[if gte IE 7]>
    z-index: 101;
<![endif]-->
z-index:99;
```

But it didnt work for me.

How can I have different valude of same property for different browsers?

Comment: Why do you want a different z-index in different browsers? You should never need to do so.

Comment: I have checked in firebug and internet web developer tool my component is working fine. Actually I have a input="file" tag on the top which I have put my own formatted button. I have kept file upload's tag opacity to 0 so that I can hide it but I have increased z-index so that I can get its functionality. Also I have kept my formatted button disabled. So when the user click the button he thinks that he is clicking button but he will be clicking that file upload tag.
In IE I have to press two times to get the file upload dialog box with the default z-index. Thats why I need 2 different z-index

Comment: That's odd- multiple clicks shouldn't change whether something is on top or not.  If you can, it'd be interesting to see what IE is doing on that first click and whether the file upload button is where you think it is.  For example, you could make the button semitransparent to test its positioning.  Even if you need a higher z-index in IE, why not just *always* use the higher z-index, even in other browsers?  That way you don't need to add this complexity to your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These comments:

```
<!--[if gte IE 7]>
```

Need to be outside your CSS code, along with your HTML markup.

For instance:

```
<!--[if gte IE 7]>
<style type="text/css">
    .selector {
        z-index: 101;
    }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Hi I tried with this. First I declared 1 more class for my component like browserSpecific class. Then I put that class in if bloack(as you have suggested) for definition. But its affecting both in firefox and ie.

Comment: sorry my mistake. It was due to some other reason. Its working smoothly. Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<style type="text/css">
  #my-div{
    z-index: 99;
  }
</style>

<!--[if gte IE 7]>
<style type="text/css">
  #my-div{
    z-index: 101;
  }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

The IE conditional comments are for HTML not CSS, so you need to bring them out of your CSS and wrap your CSS selector/logic in `<style>` tags within. Make sure that you declare your default behaviour first.

Comment: It's just to keep it lower until it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I lIke to use http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/ its easy to use especially when u have to have jquery in your website, use this insetad .
Cheers